# Read input buffer automatically after small delay

Tags: ruby

So I'm making a silly little terminal game as an excercise, and I'd like to have the user be able to type multi-char commands à la Vim, where (I assume) the user types a keystroke, then there's around a half second or so beat after the last keypress before the buffer actually gets read, so I could type d or dd and not have to hit enter.

The question is, how? I'm assuming read_nonblock is the way to go here, but how would I utilise it? My initial thought was to put it in a while loop with an incremental timer and just reset it whenever the buffer reads something new, but read_nonblock throws it's exception when the buffer is empty, so that hasn't been working...

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you use [`curses`](https://github.com/ruby/curses) or something like it? Combine that witn an [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) and you've got yourself a really basic [game engine](https://www.gameenginebook.com).

Comment: Oh I'm sure it would, but I've been explicitly trying to avoid using curses. That's part of the challenge. Also, it's an extremely simple game and using curses sort of feels like overkill.

Comment: If you avoid curses you're going to have to write your own curses, so that'll be fun. Curses does a lot of things to flip the terminal input into a really raw mode, so you can capture keypresses that don't result in characters, like depressing the shift key without typing a letter. These functions can be very OS dependent, so you'll need to check what Ruby can do with your OS. Packages like `curses` often depend on a lot of C extensions to make that happen, Ruby itself may be unable to.

Comment: While I'm a big fan of Ruby in general, it's worth noting that JavaScript does this natively and in a cross-platform way with [Electron](https://electronjs.org). Ruby has [shoes](http://shoesrb.com) but it's not really at the same level. There's also [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) which is fantastic as well. I wish there was something better Ruby could offer as an equivalent here.

Comment: I mean, it doesn't have to be an exact mimic of Vim, I'm really just looking for a way to read the buffer automatically without having to hit enter.

Comment: If your goal is to learn about low-level terminal stuff, you may want to try C, it's got unfettered, direct access to the necessary APIs. I'm not sure how you'd do this in Ruby without C extensions like `curses`, or by writing your own C extension. Both of those approaches involve a lot of learning, `curses` is not exactly easy to use because it has an incredible number of features and must support a wide variety of terminals.

Comment: I'm restricted to using Ruby for this. Believe me I wish I could throw this together in C but alas.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is what I've come up with (Adapted largely from: [this](https://gist.github.com/acook/4190379))

```ruby
$beat = 20
def read_char
  STDIN.echo = false
  STDIN.raw!

  input = STDIN.getc
  value = ""
  t = 0
  while t < $beat do
    started = Time.now
    if input != nil then
      # if input.chr == "\e" then
      #   input << STDIN.read_nonblock(3) rescue nil
      #   input << STDIN.read_nonblock(2) rescue nil
      # end
      value << input.chr
      t = 0
    else
      ended = Time.now
      t += (ended - started)*1000
    end
    input = STDIN.read_nonblock(1) rescue nil
  end
ensure
  STDIN.echo = true
  STDIN.cooked!
  return value
end
```

It seems to be working from the very basic tests I've run on it...

Comment: Great work! One minor thing to note is that it's preferred to use `$stdin` now instead of `STDIN`. This better reflects the idea that the handle is not "constant" but can in fact be reassigned, like `$stdin = StringIO.new("...")`.